# CoreAnimation - Unnecessary screen redraws on animation start cause lags

Tags: ios, performance, profiling, core-animation

There's a `CAReplicatorLayer` with a bunch of replicated `CAShapeLayers` on the screen. 
They are just shown, they don't move, nor are they supposed to do anything but be visible.

I'm running an animation to move some other `CAShapeLayers` around on the screen. As soon as the animation starts (the first time), the `CAReplicatorLayer`(with all its replications) gets redrawn. I see that due to the `CoreAnimation` profiler with "flash updated regions".

Those two things are absolutely not related at all, and though the `CAReplicatorLayer` with all its replications gets redrawn.

I've got a test project here, that shows exactly the problem. Press one of the two animation buttons to run the animation and watch the screen regions being flashed, with the `CoreAnimation` profiler active.

https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/40859730/AnimationLagTest.zip

There's a very noticable lag but only very first time the animation is run. When pressing reset, the lag begins again. On pressing reset the CAShapeLayers that are used for the animation are recreated.

I'm using an iPad 3 Retina to test this, if you have a never / faster device than me, you maybe have to increase the instanceCount of the CAReplicatorLayer to 300-1000, to see the initial lag when starting the animation.

What can I do, to stop that unnecessary re-rendering of screen regions, that obviously don't need a re-render?

Comment: What kind of animations do you use? (Do not want to download project)

Comment: CABasicAnimation and basic UIView animation. Why don't you want to download the project? It's super leight weight, and directly shows the problem.

Comment: I downloaded your code and didn't notice any lag on simulator and on iPhone 5.

Comment: Never ever test on the simulator. The simulator uses the CPU and GPU of your Mac. Try it on a real device. Preferably an iPad 3 Retina.

Comment: My mac is slow, so simulator usually works slowly then the device, especially with the retina display. As I told in my comment above, I've tested that project on iPhone 5 device, too. I've also inspected your code, it is correct and quite optimised.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have an iPhone 5 to test it on. I can only say it lags on my iPad 3 on the first animation press. Don't you see this at all? Even with maybe 1500-2000 replications?

Comment: With 1000 replications app just crashes and xcode shows "Could not run the application" error.